# Is there a name for someone who believes in Jesus as God and Savior, yet follows no sect?

Tags: religion

Do not know if I worded that right.  But was wondering what you call someone who does not believe in organized religion at all.  They may go to church but never as a member or follower of any particular group.

Comment: "Christian" could fit that person

Comment: @tunmisefashipe 'Christian' would include those that *are* part of an organized group.

Comment: Yes you are right. But there could be an Isolated Christian too. Somebody who doesn't belong anywhere and is Christ-like.

Comment: In which case the name would be 'isolated Christian' (although I don't think that's the right term).

Comment: I have been a Christian for around 30 years and have never considered myself a particular denomination, yet respect whatever denomination I happen to be involved with at the time.  I have moved a lot for work and just pick the best church in the city. It never seems to be the same denomination for some reason. Right now I am in an Anglican which I thought I would never find myself in for some reason, which I amount to ignorance now.

Answer (score 7):

I believe the word you are looking for is 'nondenominational', as in 'nondenominational Christian'. It refers to people who don't adhere to any of the subdivisions of Christianity, such as Lutheran, Catholic, Reformed etc.

The answer is made slightly confusing because there are now churches that refer to themselves as 'nondenominational', since they do not adhere to any of the larger groupings. However some of those churches are now grouping together, thus effectively creating a 'nondenominational' denomination. But in principle 'nondenominational' is a good description.

Comment: Perfect answer, though personally I prefer the term, *"bog standard"* (and count myself amongst this group).

Comment: As one who grew up "non-denominational," I quickly came to understand that "non-denominational" meant evangelical, "bible church" Christian.

Comment: + 1 - For the non-denominational demonination phrase.

Answer (score 2):

There is a growing trend amongst certain Christians to eschew denominational labels in favor of the term "[Christ-follower](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=christ%20follower)."  The implication is that an ad fontes, "it's just about Jesus and me" religion trumps any group politics.

There is more about this terminology in [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/6204/what-are-the-reasons-for-calling-oneself-a-follower-of-jesus-rather-than-a-chr)

Answer (score 2):

In *What I saw in America* Chrsterton used the terms undenominational and unsectarian to describe such folks and to my surprise, it is a real word.

> Adj.  1.  undenominational - not bound or devoted to the promotion of a particular denomination; "undenominational religious instruction"
>   nonsectarian, unsectarian - not restricted to one sect or school or party; "religious training in a nonsectarian atmosphere"; "nonsectarian colleges"; "a wide and unsectarian interest in religion"- Bertrand Russell
>   [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?word=undenominational)